# How to test ReplayKit broadcasting in iOS 10 beta?

Tags: ios, broadcast, live-streaming, ios10, replaykit

I followed the steps in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/601/ to test broadcasting of ReplayKit in the last iOS 10 beta.

I installed some live streaming apps like Mob Crush, SHOWROOM and live.ly, but still get hint that there are no live streaming apps.

Does anyone know how to test ReplayKit broadcasting in iOS 10 beta?

Thanks in advance!

[image: No live streaming app found.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just got an answer from Apple's dev team:

"Create a separate Test App which includes an empty Broadcast UI Extension and Broadcast Upload Extension. This will provide some rudimentary logging and allow you to see that the broadcast is taking place. Broadcast Extension Templates can be added to an existing iOS or tvOS project by adding a new Target in Xcode (File->New->Target->iOS or ->tvOS) and selecting Broadcast UI Extension and Broadcast Upload Extension. We recommend adding these extensions to a separate Test App (such as a newly created Xcode Game Template project, File->New->Project->iOS->Game) so you do not inadvertently include empty broadcast extensions with your final app submission."

I've tested and it work for us.